# Is predict_proba() reliable for SVC?

Tags: classification, confidence-interval, svm

I want to implement some kind of confidence measure for my stock prediction model, which predicts the next day's trend (whether the price would rise or fall). As in, a trade order should be placed only if the model is certain about its prediction up to some degree. Now decision_function() does provide a confidence measure but I can't use it, as a threshold cannot be set without actually seeing the decision_function() values of test instances.

Scikit-learn's documentation of SVC says that there are some "theoretical issues" with Platt Scaling - the method used to obtain prediction probabilities of classifiers.

Is it okay to use predic_proba() as a confidence measure?

Comment: Is your model a classification or a regression? I would expect you to be predicting asset price (or percent gain/loss) on a continuum.

Comment: It is a classification model. Predicts whether the price would rise or fall.

Comment: There’s another question on here that I suspect you e read that explains why this might not be a great idea: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/519339/247274. Sycorax makes some points that are valid here; importantly, your classes aren’t really discrete.

Comment: You should examine your model's calibration if you want to know if `predict_proba` returns reliable probability estimates.

Comment: Furthermore a probability estimate is not a confidence estimate. If you have  only one training sample, the model can predict 100% probability but with confidence intervals of [0,100%]